# An expression in access to substract numbers

Tags: ms-access

I have a table named `DispatchTracker` and in the table I have Receipt, Payment and Balance columns. Now the Balance column is a calculated field, I want a formula in the balance column that will add when cash is received and substract when payment is made.

Comment: The table name is DispatchTracker and in the table I have Receipt, Payment and Balance columns. Now the Balance column is a calculated field, I want a formula in the balance column that will add when cash is received and substract when payment is made.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, what were the results, and how are they different from what you desire

Comment: IIf(Isnull[Receipt],0,[Receipt]-IIf(Isnull[payment],0,[Payment]) it does work but it doesn't show the overall balance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A calculated field operates on the current record only.

Remove the Balance column and use a *query* to calculate the current balance.